# Failed to execute 'pushState' on 'History': function addComment() ... could not be cloned

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-router

I've tried to make my first app in React and I think I've made some serious error in the flow of the Application however trying to save it doesn't make it better.

I got my App.ksin which I have

```
<LatestRecipes latestRecipes={this.state.latestRecipes} allRecipes={this.state.recipes} addComment={this.addComment}/>
```

Right now AddComment is only:

```
addComment(key, commentData)
{
    console.log(key);
    console.log(commentData);
}
```

And in latest Recipe I have:

```
<Link to={{pathname: '/recipe/' + recipe.name, state: { recipe: recipe, index: index, addComment: this.props.addComment }}}>{recipe.name}</Link>
```

This gives me the error:

> Failed to execute 'pushState' on 'History': function addComment() ... could not be cloned.

What creates the error is the argument: 
`addComment: this.props.addComment`

if I remove it everything works but I need to pass my function thos to my Recipe component. Which is in App.js

```
<Route path="/recipe/:recipe" component={Recipe}/>
```

Which I need to pass all three arguments, recipe, index and the function addComment()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing:

```
<Route path="/recipe/:recipe" component={Recipe}/>
```

to:

```
<Route path="/recipe/:recipe" render={(props) => <Recipe {...props} addComment={this.addComment}/>} />
```

In my App.js solved it.