# How can I pass function through Link in React?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, jsx

I have to pass function through Link to another component.

```
    testFavorite=()=>{
        console.log("work")
    }

    <Link 
       to={{
       pathname: '/popular',
         state:{
            testFavorite: this.testFavorite
         }
       }}>
   Popular</Link>
```

This is how I call a function

```
this.props.location.state.testFavorite();
```

But i have this error

> history.js:370 Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'pushState' on 'History': function () { console.log("work"); } could not be cloned.

How can i fix it?
Thank you a lot

[image: Edit blazing-resonance-qgi2m]

Comment: Could you add more information in order to help you?

Comment: if I put to LInk state number or string it is pass but when I try to pass function i have a error.I think there must be a special method or something like this to pass a function.What kind of information you whant to know?

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52786072/failed-to-execute-pushstate-on-history-function-addcomment-could-not

Comment: I think this one will solve your problem [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50236502/9418800)

Comment: It help , thank you)

Answer (score 2):

It can be done when you replace state with Data.

```
<Link 
       to={{
       pathname: '/popular',
         data:{
            testFavorite: this.testFavorite
         }
       }}>
```

Also replace here

```
this.props.location.state.testFavorite();
```

Meanwhile, if you also want to pass data as props you can use state along with data

Comment: Thanks, this worked for me. Using Router v5 and was passing fn in state of Link